# How to find overlapping polygons of two shapefiles - Python

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

I have a mkl file A and a shapefile B containing polygons, each one of them having a single feature: the name associated to the polygon.

I am looking for the polygons of A which are overlapped by polygons of B using Python. In particular, I would like to know which are the best and fastest libraries to solve issues like this.

I have read [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50196/efficiently-identifying-overlapping-polygons-with-python) and the answer propose to add the geometries into a PostGIS db or to use shapely. Do you have any reference or working example from where I can learn how to properly solve this task?

Comment: You should take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). All coding question are expected to have code attempts included in the question or they will be put on hold and cant be answered.

Comment: The point is that at the moment I don't even know how to start to tackle this issue. This evening I will try to add a sample code.

Comment: Perhaps when you said "having a single feature" you meant "having a single _field_" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have loaded both files as features collections (have a look at `fiona` for that), the brute force approach is to test for intersection (or overlap, there's a slight difference between the two terms, the `shapely` documentation explains it) of all against all. This can be done in a nested loop.

```
from shapely.geometry import shape

# List to collect pairs of intersecting features
fc_intersect = []

for featA in fc_A:
    for featB in fc_B:
        if shape(featA['geometry']).intersects(shape(featB['geometry'])):
            fc_intersect.append([featA, featB])
```

If you have a lot of features on both sides, this can get very slow. Speed can be optimized by using a spatial index; that's what the `rtree` package does.

```
from rtree import index
from shapely.geometry import shape

# List to collect pairs of intersecting features
fc_intersect = []

# Instantiate index class
idx = index.Index()
for i,featA in enumerate(fc_A):
    idx.insert(i, shape(featA['geometry']).bounds)

for featB in fc_B:
    # Test for potential intersection with each feature of the other feature collection
    for intersect_maybe in idx.intersection(shape(featB['geometry']).bounds):
        # Confirm intersection
        if shape(featB['geometry']).intersects(shape(fc_B[intersect_maybe]['geometry'])):
            fc_intersect.append([fc_A[intersect_maybe], featB])
```

Comment: this is great! how can you dump this information into a df and plot it? I want to know which polygons were intersecting and calculate their area.