# Assign area of polygon to raster cell. Effective way in Python

Tags: python, raster, coordinate-system, intersection, shapely

I have quite interesting task to resolve, but my solution is not effective, so I am looking for some advice to improve my code. I have raster dataset covering Europe, in crs WGS 1984 (4326). The cells of the raster are the basic statistic units. I have polygon shapefile (already projected to crs 3035, etrs89 / etrs-laea) and for each pixel I need to know relative area that is covered by forest. So, I need to create output raster, that will show percentage of forest in each pixel.

Since I am new in Python, with a help of many responses here SE (mostly [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311194/how-to-find-overlapping-polygons-of-two-shapefiles-python)), I was able to compose a working script, that work such I want, nonetheless is super-ineffective. For small area it works great, but for rasters of huge size is useless, because calculating 1 pixel takes about 1 second in my PC. My raster has 12300 x 6000 (73 800 000) pixels.

My next step probably would be to learn use the parallel processing, but first I want to do my code much more efficient.

I faced a lot of problems and my solutions aren´t probably the best ones:

1. I didn´t find better way than artificially create polygon "frame" for each pixel and than intersect it with every forest polygon. Is there a better way? Tried to use the spatial indices and bounding box selection.
2. Input and output raster must be in WGS 84. But it´s not possible to measure area in this crs, because it is in degrees. So I am using crs 3035 to measure it. But it means that every polygon "frame" of every pixel I need to project into this crs.
3. Some of the shp polygons of forests are not valid. I found out that help if I apply buffer(0) to them.
4. Decided to write the result into an array and than the array convert into raster with same properties like the original raster. Don´t know better solution.

```py
import gdal
from shapely.geometry import  Polygon, shape
from shapely.ops import transform
from rtree import index
import time
import pyproj
import fiona

shp = fiona.open("./forests.shp") #load polygons of forests
grid = gdal.Open("D:/anaconda/corine_calc/CHELSA_temp_1_1979-2013_V1.2.tif") #load raster

rasterArray = grid.ReadAsArray() #create array of same size as raster - for saving new values
rasterArray[0:len(rasterArray)] = 0 #set all cells to 0

##get info of the raster
grid.GetProjection()
info = grid.GetGeoTransform()
print (info)
spX = info[0]  #starting point
spY = info[3]
pixelSizeX = info[1] size X
pixelSizeY = info[5] #size Y
cols = grid.RasterXSize
rows = grid.RasterYSize
print(cols* rows) #cells in raster
##

#create spatial indeces for polygons of forests
pol_idx = index.Index() 
for i, featA in enumerate(shp):
    pol_idx.insert(i, shape(featA['geometry']).bounds)

#definition of transformation
project = pyproj.Transformer.from_proj(
    pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326'), # source coordinate system
    pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:3035')) # destination coordinate system

for col in range(cols): #and now the critical part
    for row in range(rows): # col x row = each "pixel" cell
        nw = [spX + col * pixelSizeX, spY + row * pixelSizeY] #get corner coordinates of the pixel
        ne = [spX + (col+1) * pixelSizeX, spY + row * pixelSizeY]
        sw = [spX + col * pixelSizeX, spY + (row+1) * pixelSizeY]
        se = [spX + (col+1) * pixelSizeX, spY + (row+1) * pixelSizeY]
        poly = Polygon([nw, ne, se, sw]) #create shapely polygon out of them
        poly_transformed = transform(project.transform, poly) #apply new projection to new polygon
        for intersect_maybe in pol_idx.intersection(poly_transformed.bounds): #find intersection of bboxes
            if poly_transformed.intersects(shape(shp[intersect_maybe]['geometry']).buffer(0)): #if it really intersects
                rasterArray[row, col] = rasterArray[row, col] + (poly_transformed.intersection(shape(shp[intersect_maybe]['geometry']).buffer(0)).area)  #add the area of intersection to array
        rasterArray[row, col] = round((rasterArray[row, col] / poly_transformed.area)*100) #for each cell calculate the relative size of intersection polygons

 #define output raster
outRaster = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create("./out_raster3.tif", grid.RasterXSize, grid.RasterYSize, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
outRaster.SetProjection(grid.GetProjectionRef())
outRaster.SetGeoTransform(info)
outRaster.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(255)
outRaster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(rasterArray)
outRaster.FlushCache()
outRaster = None #close
```